# React Widget Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jsx

I have build a react widget that could be embedded into any website by following the article [here](https://javascriptpros.com/creating-react-widgets-embedded-anywhere/). Initially, I had bee doing development on a ubuntu machine where I embedded this on a simple test.html page and it ran perfectly fine.

Now, I moved my dev env to a macOS and suddenly the same test.html is throwing me error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at widgetIndex.jsâ€:1:1)
```

Nothing has changed, on my ubuntu machine the widget runs great but on my mac its not running instead I got a cross origin error. I fired up a node server to server the test.html page and got the above error.

Here is the test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
   
<script type="text/javascript"  defer src=“http://localhost:7171/widget/widgetIndex.js”></script>
</head>
<body>
hello world
<div class="hype_widget" widget-id="4SJQ1ZS7hOMThnbhHQZjVS"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

A screenshot of localhost serving the widgetIndex.js file
[image]

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@react-keycloak/web": "^3.4.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "jquery": "^3.6.4",
    "keycloak-js": "^20.0.3",
    "material-react-table": "^1.11.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.4",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-notifications-component": "^4.0.1",
    "react-phone-input-2": "^2.15.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-select": "^5.7.3",
    "react-select-country-list": "^2.2.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "build:widget": "parcel build src/widget/widgetIndex.js --no-source-maps --dist-dir build/widget",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "buffer": "^5.7.1",
    "parcel": "^2.8.3"
  }
}
```

However, I serve this react widget on tomcat server via pom.xml

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.12.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build:widget</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build:widget</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>src/main/webapp</workingDirectory>
                    <nodeVersion>v20.2.0</nodeVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/static</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/webapp/build</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I tried using babel but nothing happens. The error goes away but the js file is not downloaded in source of the browser.

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.7.7/babel.min.js">    </script>
   
<script type="text/babel"  src=“http://localhost:7171/widget/widgetIndex.js”></script>
```